# Cuantos For y donde los debo usar?

Tags: python, bucle-for

Hola estoy haciendo un programita de 3d con Python y utilizo json para cargar los datos por ejemplo
`data = {'Cube':[1,2,3],'Cube':[]}`
los números son la posición del objeto
el tema es

```
for i in list(data.keys()):
    if i == 'block':
        cube = Cube(position=(data[i]))
```

Hago esto para generar los cubos en cada posición pero solo genera 1 y no se donde debería ir otro `for` para que lo haga para todos, el proyecto es muy largo solo pasare esto:

```
json = {'block':[12,5,12],
       'block':[24,5,24]}


for i in list(json.keys()):
   if i == 'block':
       print(f'cube: {json[i]}')
```

este código es con lo que probé en otro script limpio sin todo el motor 3D
recomendarían que trabajen sobre este ya que el otro no es el original el otro tiene unas cosas cambiadas

Comment: las llaves de los diccionarios no pueden ser repetidas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La llave de un diccionario debe ser única. Cuando usas

```
json = {'block':[12,5,12],
       'block':[24,5,24]}
```

la segunda entrada `block` reemplaza a la primera.

**Demo**

```
json = {'block':[12,5,12],
       'block':[24,5,24]}

print(json)
```

produce:

```
{'block': [24, 5, 24]}

Process finished with exit code 0
```

#### Solución

La solución más simple es hacer una lista de las posiciones y guardarla en el diccionario:

```
json = {'block':[[12,5,12], [24,5,24]]}

print(json)
for bloque in json['block']:
    print(bloque)
```

produce:

```
{'block': [[12, 5, 12], [24, 5, 24]]}
[12, 5, 12]
[24, 5, 24]

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: ok, pero que pasaría si para cada bloque quisiera añadirle un PATH para la textura, donde y como debería añadir el PATH de la textura

Comment: Debes crear una clase `Bloque` que contenga todos los parámetros necesarios (posición, textura, etc.). En la lista ahora almacenas objectos de la clase `Bloque`, no simples lista de coordenadas. El objeto contiene toda la información que requieras.

Answer (score 0):

Cuando se tiene un conjunto de datos que compartan la misma estructura, usualmente se usan arreglos para almacenarlos. En este caso los cubos, por lo que dices, comparten propiedades pero no valores, por lo que la forma de almacenarlos debería ser algo como esto:

```
[{'posicion':[12,5,12], "otro_parametro":1},{'posicion':[24,5,24], "otro_parametro":2}]
```

Es decir una lista de diccionarios.
Un diccionario no serviría para listar distintos objetos de la misma clase, porque la idea de los diccionarios es que no repitan propiedades. Un json, por otra parte,  podría o no funcionar, porque la forma "[1,2,3]" es un json válido, que sería equivalente a una lista en python, pero la forma '{"propiedad":"valor"}', equivalente a un diccionario, no podría funcionar.